# Write a list of lists into csv and having UnicodeEncodeError in python

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, csv, xlsm

I am converting an xlsm file to csv using the openpyxl library.
I have the problem that when I try to pass the list of lists to the csv python returns the following error:

*Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 21, in 
listIntoCsv(finalList)
File "test.py", line 16, in listIntoCsv
write.writerows(list)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xfa' in position 20: ordinal not in range(128)*

These are 2 example of 1 list inside the final list:

```
[
[u'0@jordilazo.com', u'SZHK@jordilazo.es, NFUW@jordilazo.es', 
datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 18, 10, 7, 16),
1L, '0', 1L, 2L, 'NO', 
None, 'test@jordilazo.es',
'TEST@jordilazo.es', None,
None, False, False, None,None,
False, False, False, None, None,
True, 'SI', 'N/A',3182L, 0L, None,
None, None, '#N/A', 'RE: N< >LWWM',
u'a9e5bbbb497', u'Com: \xd1<GR A', None]...
]
```

I am executing the code with python2. I have tried to apply different solutions so that the code looks like this:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import csv
import codec

  excelFile = load_workbook('test.xlsm', data_only=True)
  currentSheet = excelFile.worksheets[0]
  
  def iter_rows(currentSheet):
    for row in currentSheet.iter_rows():
      yield [cell.value for cell in row]

  def listIntoCsv(list):
    with codecs.open('test','w',encoding='UTF-8') as f:
      write = csv.writer(f)
      write.writerows(list)
  
  finalList = list(iter_rows(currentSheet))
  print(finalList)
  listIntoCsv(finalList)
```

Comment: That isn't your actual code; you have `define` instead of `def`.  Exactly which line gives you that error?  The error shows 'ascii' encoding, but you have `encoding='UTF-8'`.

Comment: I just now noticed you're using Python 2.  It looks like you'll need to write an adapter to encode the Unicode strings delivered by openpyxl into UTF-8.  Check the helper classes at the bottom of the doc page:  https://python.readthedocs.io/en/v2.7.2/library/csv.html

Comment: As you said I had to create adapter for the values of my excel. I share my own solution for my problem (its not the best but it works for the moment). Thanks Tom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to change the type of each element inside the list we have to change them manually by changing their type to string due to python 2.7 does not support unicode format. So the solution is:

```
from types import NoneType
import unicodedata
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import csv
from datetime import datetime
import os
  
  def dateTimeToUnixTIme(dateTime):
    dataTimeObject = datetime.datetime.strptime(dateTime, "%Y-%m-%d 
    %H:%M:%S.%f")
    unixTime = time.mktime(dataTimeObject.timetuple()) + 
    (dataTimeObject.microsecond / 1000000.0)
    return unixTime

  def iterRows(currentSheet):
    for row in currentSheet.iter_rows():
      yield [cell.value for cell in row]

  def listIntoCsv(list):
    with open('excel.csv','w') as f:
      write = csv.writer(f)
      write.writerows(list)
  

  def decodeList(list):
    for x,y in enumerate(list):
      for j,element in enumerate(y):
        if isinstance(element,unicode):
          element = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', 
          element).encode('ascii', 'ignore')
          if (", ") in element and '@' in element:
            element = element.replace(' ','')
            element = element.split(",")
            list[x][j] = element
          list[x][j] = element

        elif isinstance(element,date):
          element = element.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
          element = dateTimeToUnixTIme(element)
          list[x][j] = str(element)

        elif isinstance(element,(long,int,float)):
          element = str(element)
          list[x][j] = element

        elif isinstance(element,NoneType):
          element = str(element).replace('None','Nada')
          list[x][j] = element

        elif isinstance(element,bool):
          element = str(element)
          list[x][j] = element

        elif isinstance(element,str):
          element = str(element)
          list[x][j] = element
        else:
          list[x][j] = element

  return list

  ubicationExcel = 'bin/mailList/Investigacion_DLP_enmascarado.xlsm'
  excelFile = load_workbook(ubicationExcel, data_only=True)
  currentSheet = excelFile.worksheets[0]
  dirtyList = list(iterRows(currentSheet))
  finalList = encodeList(dirtyList)
  listIntoCsv(finalList)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).